# How to insert json document using Java in postgres

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I Have a postgres db -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS records (
   "value" jsonb,
   "tags" jsonb
);
```

How should I define my class - such that a json document goes in the value and tags column?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "records")

public class RecordEntity implements Serializable {

    private String value;      

    private String tags;

}
```

What annotation or data type should I give to value and tags - such that a json document goes in postgres table.

Comment: Please let me know if the answer helps you or is it what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hibernate-types` library to map a String JPA property to a JSON database column. The `hibernate-types` framework is very flexible and allows you to use a String JPA property type to represent a JSON structure.

```
@Entity(name= "RecordEntity")
@Table(name = "records")
@TypeDef(
        name ="json",
        typeClass = JsonType.class
)
public class RecordEntity implements Serializable {
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private String value;
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private String tags;
}
```

To use hibernate-types add following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-55</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

More details could be found in this post: [How to map a String JPA property to a JSON column using Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-string-jpa-property-json-column-hibernate/)

Comment: while the reference may have answer, it will always be helpful to add the content of the answer here and do refer it later for more clarity.

Comment: Sure, makes sense. I will do that.

Comment: HI @FelixKJose, It is giving the following error :- ERROR: column "value" is of type json but expression is of type bytea

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that your type was just `json`, I have provided the example for type `jsonb`. I have updated the example, the modification is just `@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")` to `@Column(columnDefinition = "json")`

Comment: @HarshMultani Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: @FelixKJose, No, it should be jsonb, only. My mistake there. I am using jsonb only and the same error occurs. I have edited it.

Comment: @HarshMultani Could you share your exact exception?